# Forward console output to computer

Tags: adb, terminal

Is there a way to forward the console output of your phone (I'm assuming there is some because Linux) to your computer, maybe using ADB? I'm especially interested in how to get the boot time messages, because I suspect there are quite some errors going on.

If it matters, I have a Samsung Galaxy GIO.

Answer (score 0):

Running `adb logcat` and rebooting my phone worked for me. Requires the Android SDK though.